# Cannot download files anymore

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I've got a system where we're using a Service Account to connect to the Google Drive SDK. It's been working fine for about 6 months, but starting a week ago, with no code changes, it's no longer able to download files from the Google Drive. We're still able to List files, but downloads are now bouncing to an authorization page rather than downloading the file. I'm certain that my Service Account has permissions to the file.

To down the file, I use the following code:

```
var downloader = new MediaDownloader(driveService);
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var download = await downloader.DownloadAsync(file.Url, stream);
if (download.Exception != null) throw download.Exception;
// Reset to the begining for replay
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
return stream;
```

Comment: What scope are you using?  Check the directory and the file permissions to be sure the service account has access.

Comment: My scopes are `DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.Drive`. My service account has access to both the directory and the file. I'm able to list the file, and can see the service account on the permissions. Also recall that this DID work, then mysteriously stopped working, with no code changes, so I don't think it's likely to be a a scoping issue.

Comment: Does the official sample https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples/tree/master/Drive.Sample works as is if you just change your auth parameters?

Comment: Any chance you've got some restrictions in place? https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?visit_id=636881108777054829-379209440&rd=1#api_key_restrictions

Comment: Are you using API v2 or v3?

Comment: @SimonMourier The official sample uses OAuth, not a Service Account, so I kinda doubt it's going to be that enlightening.

Comment: @AwonDanag v3 via the latest Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/

Comment: @AndrewHarris Good idea to check that. No current restrictions. I'm well within my API usage limits.

Comment: You're confusing the auth method with the type of account. You can try the sample with the secret json file that you have for your service account.

Comment: Are downloading from specific folder on a specific account ? or it's dynamic (variable) folder on a dynamic (variable) account ?

Comment: @heneryville, are you able to show how you create driveService?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

- You can share
- The folder of (xxxxx@gmail.com)
- With  (xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com)
- then **the same code will work**

### Why

- There are 2 users :

  - GClould service account (xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com)
  - Google Drive account (xxxxx@gmail.com)
- You can't use your GClould service account to access Google Drive App

### How

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and this worked for me:

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = service.Files.Get(fileId).Execute();
if (!file.MimeType.Equals("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"))
{
    //for files use another Url
    exportUrl = file.DownloadUrl;
}
var response = service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(exportUrl).Result;
Stream downloadStream = new MemoryStream(response);
```